What is "moral autonomy"?
Currently reading David Graeber's Direct Action: an ethnography and he mentions "taking [...] the principle of moral autonomy seriously" (p 223). I wondered if anyone here could explain this principle in a more simplified way? Thanks.

Okay I found this online and hopefully it helps someone: "Moral autonomy, usually traced back to Kant, is the capacity to deliberate and to give oneself the moral law, rather than merely heeding the injunctions of others".

It may be helpful to add that without moral autonomy, ie. the capacity to independent moral judgement and action, it is hard to argue for moral and legal responsibility for one's actions. It is, therefore, pretty important as a concept.
